# Sorting DateTimeSeries duplicates in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Alright so I hope we don't need an example for this, but let's say we have a DataFrame with 100k rows and 50+ instances of the Index being the exact same DateTime.

What would be the fastest way to sort my DataFrame by Time, but then if there is a tie choose a second column to sort by.

So:

```
Sort By Time
If Duplicate Time, sort by 'Cost'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a list of the columns in the order you want them sorted by it will sort by the first column and then the second column

```
df = DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,1,3], 'b':[1,2,2,2,1]})

df

Out[11]:

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  3  1

In [13]:

df.sort(columns=['a','b'], inplace=True)

df

Out[13]:

   a  b
0  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  2
1  2  2
4  3  1
```

So for your example

```
df.sort(columns=['Time', 'Cost'],inplace=True)
```

would work

**EDIT**

It has pointed out (by @AndyHayden) that there is bug if you have nested NaN in supplementary columns, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126500/pandas-nested-sort-and-nan) and there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3917), this may not be an issue in your case but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this fails with NaN: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3917

Comment: Yea the NaN is the problem.