# possible bug in pandas sort with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

If I make a dataframe like the following:

```
In [128]: test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,2,7,3,6], 'b':[2,2,2,1,1,1], 'c':[2,6,np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN]})
In [129]: test
Out[129]:
   a  b   c
0  1  2   2
1  4  2   6
2  2  2 NaN
3  7  1 NaN
4  3  1   1
5  6  1 NaN
```

basic sorts perform as expected. Sorting on column c appropriately segregates the nan values. Doing a multi-level sort on columns a and b orders them as expected:

```
In [133]: test.sort(columns='c', ascending=False)
Out[133]:
   a  b   c
5  6  1 NaN
3  7  1 NaN
2  2  2 NaN
1  4  2   6
0  1  2   2
4  3  1   1

In [134]: test.sort(columns=['b', 'a'], ascending=False)
Out[134]:
   a  b   c
1  4  2   6
2  2  2 NaN
0  1  2   2
3  7  1 NaN
5  6  1 NaN
4  3  1   1
```

But doing a multi-level sort with columns b and c does not give the expected result:

```
In [135]: test.sort(columns=['b', 'c'], ascending=False)
Out[135]:
   a  b   c
1  4  2   6
0  1  2   2
2  2  2 NaN
3  7  1 NaN
4  3  1   1
5  6  1 NaN
```

And, in fact, even sorting just on column c but using the multi-level sort nomenclature fails:

```
In [136]: test.sort(columns=['c'], ascending=False)
Out[136]:
   a  b   c
1  4  2   6
0  1  2   2
2  2  2 NaN
3  7  1 NaN
4  3  1   1
5  6  1 NaN
```

I would think that this should have given the exact same result as line 133 above. Is this a pandas bug or is there something I'm not getting? (FYI, pandas v0.11.0, numpy v1.7.1, python 2.7.2.5 32bit on windows 7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas nested sort and NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126500/pandas-nested-sort-and-nan)

Comment: I noticed that test.sort(columns='c', ascending=False).sort(columns='b', ascending=False) does give the correct answer in this case. But I don't know if that's a robust solution. Anyone have a thought?

Comment: That will only work if pandas sorting algorithm is stable.  I didn't find anything in the docs (and numpy's sorting algorithm is not stable by default).  I'm trying to find the source now....

Comment: @mgilson checkout this [bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3917) on this

Comment: it calls `k.argsort` ... where `k` is a column of the dataframe -- Presumably this is a numpy array which gives the indices to tell pandas how to re-order the data.  Unfortunatetly, np.argsort uses (by default) the `quicksort` algorithm which isn't stable, so your solution isn't 100% robust.

Comment: @AndyHayden -- I'm glad unutbu's on it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting corner case.  Note that even vanilla python doesn't get this "correct":

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> a = [ 6, 2, nan, nan, 1, nan]
>>> sorted(a)
[2, 6, nan, nan, 1, nan]
```

The reason here is because `NaN` is neither greater nor less than the other elements -- So there is no strict ordering defined.  Because of this, `python` leaves them alone.

```
>>> nan > 6
False
>>> nan < 6
False
```

Pandas must make an explicit check in the single column case -- probably using `np.argsort` or `np.sort` as starting at numpy 1.4, `np.sort` puts `NaN` values at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads up above. I guess this is already a known issue. One stopgap solution I came up with is:

```
test['c2'] = test.c.fillna(value=test.c.min() - 1)
test.sort(['b', 'c2'])
test = test.drop('c2', axis = 1)
```

This method wouldn't work in regular numpy since .min() would return nan, but in pandas it works fine.

Comment: Numpy does have a `nanmin` function I believe :).